# What is the best way to assign environment variable inside chef recipe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I want to assign a system variable within chef recipe
I am using the following code:

```
env 'DEF_ADDR' do
  value "http://#{node['ipaddress']}"
end
```

However, I am getting the below error on executing the recipe

> ERROR: Cannot find a resource for env on redhat version 6.6

Comment: What is the problem that you actually want to achieve? You want to run some command?

Comment: achieve -> solve :-)

Comment: yes - it all depends on how you later want to *use* the environment variable

Answer (score 1):

The [`env` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_env.html) seems to be only for Windows environments:

> Use the env resource to manage environment keys in Microsoft Windows.

If you want to define an environment variable only for the Chef Run, you can use Ruby:

```
ENV['DEF_ADDR'] = "http://#{node['ipaddress']}"
```

But this will only be accessible during the Chef Run.

If you want to define a system-wide environment variable, maybe the [`etc_environment`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/etc_environment) cookbook could help you with that:

```ruby
node.default['etc_environment']['DEF_ADDR'] = "http://#{node['ipaddress']}"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no consistent way to set global environment variables on Unix. Some distros support global-level shell includes via things like `/etc/profile.d` and the like, but this will have no effect on things run outside of a shell like direct SSH execution or running as a service.